# Google Cloud Build failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, devops, google-cloud-build

I am experience issue in cloud build. I am trying to deploy test terraform resource in google cloud.

Below is Error Snapshot I am facing ,

[image: ERROR]

Below is build steps i am using,

```
substitutions:
  _TERRAFORM_VERSION: 1.0.0

options:
  logging: 'CLOUD_LOGGING_ONLY'
  #env: ['TF_VERSION=1.0.0']

steps:
- id: 'terraform init'
  name: 'hashicorp/terraform:${_TERRAFORM_VERSION}'
  entrypoint: sh
  args: 
    - '-c'
    - |
      terraform init && terraform validate && terraform plan  -out=myplan

- id: 'checkov stage'
  name: 'bridgecrew/checkov:latest'
  entrypoint: 'bash'
  args:
    - '-c'
    - |
      checkov -d . --quiet || true

- id: 'Terraform Apply'
  name: 'hashicorp/terraform:${_TERRAFORM_VERSION}'
  entrypoint: 'bash'
  args:
    - '-c'
    - |
      terraform apply --auto-approve myplan
```

Any Idea in which case this happened?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Please share your build or specific step file for ref.

Comment: Can you share your Cloud Build step definition?

Comment: You are using a container that does not have the `bash` program. You are specifying using `bash` in your third step. https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/configuring-builds/run-bash-scripts#using_the_script_field Note: Terraform is a real executable program. You do not need to use `bash` to run it.

Answer (score 0):

Your `terraform init` step is using `sh`, and your `terraform apply` step is is using `bash`.

It would appear that the image you're using for terraform doesn't have the `bash` executable on the PATH.

I think if you just changed `bash` to `sh` on the last build step, it should work.